# Google places: changes input placeholder

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm using Google's Places API to implement a search bar within my app that returns addresses based on user input. You can find more information on how to use these APIs at the following link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview

Everything works perfectly, except for the placeholder of my search bar, which I can't set correctly without using a trick.

I am using an ion-searchbar.

> ```
>  <ion-searchbar
>                 id="searchAddress"
>                 color="light"
>                 onIonCancel={() => this.searchAddress({target: {value: ''}})}
>                 onIonInput={(ev) => this.searchAddress(ev)}
>                 show-clear-button="focus"
>                 placeholder={i18n("search-by-station")}>
>             </ion-searchbar>
> ```

the problem is that the placeholder that I see is "insert a query".

At the componentdidload I do this to target my searchbar as a google input.
without the timeout, the placeholder remains "insert a query" and using the timeout when I load the component I see a bad effect of the placeholder that changes to the wanted one.

> ```
> componentDidLoad() {
>
>     this.inputSearchbar = document.getElementById('searchAddress') as any;
>     this.searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(this.inputSearchbar);
>
>  
>     setTimeout(() => {
>        
>         this.inputSearchbar.placeholder = i18n("search-by-station");
>     }, 500);  
> }
> ```

Someone solved the same problem?
Thanks